# how to solve the pods FailedMount problem

Tags: microk8s, kubelet

when I use the command `microk8s kubectl describe pods test-pod`, I found that there is a problem in the pod, so the pod's status is ContainerCreating.
How to solve this problem?

Warning  FailedMount             31s (x8 over 98s)  kubelet                  MountVolume.SetUp failed for volume "pvc-ed14af50-00b6-4d15-ae03-4258edb8a895" : rpc error: code = Unknown desc = create target path: mkdir /var/snap/microk8s/common/var/lib/kubelet/pods/4da58c56-76d0-4ea2-a1f1-e571481f2bd4/volumes/kubernetes.io~csi/pvc-ed14af50-00b6-4d15-ae03-4258edb8a895/mount: no such file or directory

I hope the pod--test-pod can be running status

Comment: The error message looks a mess: did you copy it verbatim?